# Linux device node for M.2 disks

Tags: linux, hard-drive, sata

Simply put: Would an M.2 disk via a SATA III interface register as `/dev/sdX` in linux?

Due to odd requirements from a suite of proprietary software, the main disk must register as either `sda` or `hda`, and for this reason I had issues with using a laptop with an NVMe drive (it registered as `/dev/nvme0` or something along those lines).

In short: Is it safe to asume that anything connected via the SATA III interface will register as `/dev/sdX`, be it RPM-disks, SSDs, or punchcards?

Comment: If it doesn't, just use a symbolic link

Comment: Can't say for sure that all will, but those that I tried all registered as /dev/sdX

Comment: @Aki Did you try anything "out of the ordinary"

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but I don't think so. I currently use a Samsung 850 EVO M.2 via SATA III that is registered as /dev/sda using Arch Linux.